# Apache hive Windowing functions lag and lead error

Tags: hadoop, apache-hive

I am trying to select lead and lag value from a column using  LAG and LEAD functions. Below are table and data.

```
hive> select * from foo;                                                      
OK
a
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Time taken: 0.923 seconds
```

When I try to select lead and lag value, the following error is throwing.

```
hive> select LAG(a, 1) over (order by a) as previous, a, LEAD(a, 1) over (order by a) as next from foo;
FAILED: ParseException line 1:22 missing FROM at '(' near '(' in subquery source
line 1:23 cannot recognize input near 'order' 'by' 'a' in subquery source
```

How to solve tis issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can see "partition by" clause is missing in the statement.

```
Select lead(a,1) over (partition by a order by a) as next from foo;
```

It won't be useful to run on just one column in table, if you have more columns like date/time, category, it will work.